# Only perform operation on exiting list using stream() and don't return any collection object

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying Java 8 stream() API to perform some operations but I am unable to achieve required output.

Only update existing list and I don't want to return updated list. Please check below query and what I am trying for the same.

1. I want to assign ids to students for whom id is not assigned i.e. for that objects id is null or blank. So I just want to perform this operation and don't want anything in return and below is what I am trying but I am not getting how to stop this operation without returning updated list.

   ```
   students.stream().filter(StringUtils.isNullOrBlank(s->s.getId())).map(e-> e.setId(randomNum++))
   ```
2. Another one is I want to get the list of student names for which id get updated. I am trying below 2 different operations but can we do it in one?

   ```
   List<Student> studList = 
   employees.stream().filter(StringUtils.isNullOrBlank(s->s.getId())).map(e-> e.setId(randomNum++)).collect(Collectors.toList());
   List<String> names = studList.stream().map(s->s.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

Comment: If you want to update the existing list then `stream` is the wrong thing to use. But it doesn't look like you want to change the list, you just want to call a method on each element, so why not use `forEach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a `Stream` *and* you don't care about collecting the result, then you can use a terminal operation such as [`forEach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)) (very similar to the [`forEach` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)) that you can find on a `Collection`, inherited from `Iterable`):

```
students.stream()
    .filter(StringUtils.isNullOrBlank(s->s.getId()))
    .forEach(e-> e.setId(randomNum++));
```

If however, you want to collect something about those students, then you can use [`peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek(java.util.function.Consumer)) to get a side-effect running:

```
List<String> names = students.stream()
    .filter(StringUtils.isNullOrBlank(s->s.getId()))
    .peek(e-> e.setId(randomNum++))
    .map(Student::getName)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will set an ID on each id-less Student and return a list of names of those students.